# Azure DevOps Mermaid labels not centered

Tags: azure-devops, mermaid

### Question

**Is it possible to change my Azure DevOps wiki's Mermaid configurations? Or is there any other way for me to get my desired result on my wiki?**

Desired Result:

[image: VS Code Rendered]

### Details

Using the Mermaid markdown in an Azure DevOps wiki, the label in the nodes is not center aligned.

Example markdown

```
:::mermaid
graph LR
    start(Begin) --> setup(Setup Station)
    setup --> select{select<br>test function}
:::
```

Resulting Flowchart:

[image: Azure DevOps Wiki Rendered]

I found this issue on the Mermaid github:

[Label texts in flowcharts are not centered horizontally with "htmlLabels" disabled #1177](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/issues/1177)

The issue mentions that the alignment works properly if the `flowchart` configuration has `htmlLables: true`.

I cant find where on my Azure DevOps wiki to make changes to the mermaid configuration. I have dug around the site and tried cloning the wiki but cant find any files or pages containing the mermaid configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping the mermaid graph in a center tag will center all the text in all nodes within the graph. There must be a blank line between the center tag and the graph opening/closing
or the graph will be treated as plain text.

```
<center>

:::mermaid
graph LR
    start(Begin) --> setup(Setup Station)
    setup --> select{select<br>test function}
:::

</center>
```

Giving the desired Result:

[image: Desired Result]

Down sides:

- Have to apply to all nodes, can't be selective
- centers graph on pages as well.

I am willing to accept these compromises to have centered text and in my case they are a non-issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your example in one team project of my DevOps Service-- Overview --Wiki, the labels are centered automatically. Check the screenshot below:

[image]

———————————————————————————————————————————

**Update:**

DevOps doesn't support change the format, you may submit a suggestion at website https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21.

As a workaround, this can be controlled by the browser. Check my following example, if you add `text-align:center` to the `style`, the label in the nodes is center aligned.

[image]

Comment: Note `select<br>test` is not centered `test` is left justified, it can also be more noticeable with longer strings such as `select function to<br>test`

Comment: I have edited my question so it has a more noticeable example of the error.

Comment: Unfortunately, DevOps doesn't support change the format, you may submit a suggestion at website https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21. You may try to modify the browser site style as a workaround.